# SQL Server connection with UWP app and VB.NET is not working

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, uwp

I hope someone can help me. The code shown here connects perfectly well to my remote SQL Server, but when used in an UWP application, it hangs the app and sometimes throws a network connection error, but does not want to connect and retrieve any info from the SQL Server.

```
Dim str As String = "Data Source=SQLSERVER-ADDRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=******"
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(str)
    
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID, FName, LName FROM Users" '"SELECT ID, FName, Name FROM Users" 
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

conn.Open()

Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

While rdr.Read()
    Dim str2 As String = "" & rdr(1) & " " & rdr(2)
    user_list_listbox.Items.Add(str2)

End While

conn.Close()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860880/11683?

Comment: I checked and have all the required capabilities selected, but still does not want to connect

Comment: There are so many things that could go wrong that error messages are fairly important to diagnosing problems. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70617678/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: Ok, so it seems that after removing and adding the System.Data.SqlClient through Nuget again, it started giving a different issue. Now it does not want to connect but gives a SSL Provider, handshake failed error. Any assistance would be highly 

Here is the error

_System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)'

Inner Exception
EndOfStreamException: End of stream reached_

Comment: _Initial Catalog=master_ Nope - you should NOT be using this system database for your own tables.

Comment: Regardless, I am still having the connection issue. No matter which database I am trying to connect to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ)